# Identity Server 4 / OpenID Connect default redirect URL

Tags: identityserver4

I'm getting started with Identity Server 4 (under ASP.NET Core) using the Implicit flow to secure an Angular 2 front end (to Web API services).

Using the [oidc-client JS library](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/), I can successfully redirect from the sample's default page to my login page, have the user authenticate, then redirect (via /connect/authorize) back the the Angular site's callback.

If a user browses *directly* to my authentication login page (rather than the Angular home page), I can then authenticate, but have nowhere to redirect to. If I redirect manually to the auth server's /connect/authorize page, the OIDC Client reports "No matching state found in storage". (Presumably, the OIDC Client is persisting something locally to verify the response against the original request?).

An obvious solution is for the Auth server to redirect any requests without a redirect specified to the Angular client, which could then redirect back to the Auth server as normal. That feels like a lot of round trips though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - because this is not how it works. The authentication flow starts at the client application - not the identity provider.

An OpenID Connect provider typically has more then one client - so it needs contextual information (aka a valid OIDC authorize request).

If you want that the journey starts at the provider you need to do something like you proposed - but once you have a 2nd client you need to be smarter about that (e.g. a selection screen etc).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to confirm I wasn't too far aware. (The reality is, some users will always bookmark the login page, so from that point of view, it is how it works, at least on occasion.) Google (for example) does pretty much as you say and redirects to an account admin page as a default.

Really appreciate your comments; thanks.